# I really want to use Xapian on a project, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to install it on Windows!

Tags: xapian

If this was on a linux box I'd be set, but there's a distinct lack of documentation!

I want to use this with c# and the omega indexing app.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to actually BUILD xapian & omega on windows (or, pre-compiled binaries which would work fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I published an article on what I had to do to get this up and running: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/XapianUnderWindows.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the Windows precompiled binaries, I'm happy to help if I can - you can reach me via the Flax website.

Comment: The issue is that the documentation on how to use the build files is poor.

I'm going to have to spend the time to build the doc on what I did to get it working (and the pitfalls 32bit v 64bit)...

Comment: Here's the article I posted about how to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/XapianUnderWindows.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the Xapian [downloads page](http://xapian.org/download): it says you can use Cygwin or MSYS+mingw or makefiles for MSVC and pre-built binaries

Comment: I read that... cygwin on a prod server is a non-starter.  And I've never used msys/mingw before.  The learning curve is steep to say the least.  I do have it compiling now in msys+mingw though.

Comment: Let us know how it goes. I am tempted to say "use the best platform for the toolkit" and clearly in this case its *nix-based.

Comment: I got it compiled with mysys/mingw (slowly) but the lack of doc made me toss my hands up.  I revisited it and compiled it with vcpp and it worked (again, lack of doc made this way more difficult than it needed to be) and then realized I didn't need to compile it (the bindings had what was needed).  Then the downloadable bindings (and the ones I built) are 32bit... all my boxen and servers are 64 bit, and running this in wow mode (asp.net) simply isn't going to fly.  I punted and am looking at lucene.net now.

Comment: I changed the source files as needed and compiled it for x64 and it did compile and worked fine in x64 mode, but there were a TON of compiler warnings re:loss of precision from __int64->int and I can't run something like that on a prod box.

Answer (score 0):

You can download binaries and all you need to build recent releases of Xapian, Omega and most of the language bindings on Windows using Microsoft Visual C++ 7.0 or above from here:

http://www.flax.co.uk/xapian_windows.shtml

Comment: "all" is really not enough since the doc on how to compile, etc. is pretty weak.  I did get it though...

Comment: Can I suggest then that you post on the Xapian-discuss list, as they are usually very responsive there... http://lists.xapian.org/mailman/listinfo/xapian-discuss

Comment: This link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a great job modifying header files and stuff, but as a windows user I miss a classical - build your dll and forget it.

It seems really weird that this application does not seem to have a simple dll that php extension and everything else can link to.

I need to write my own kwd producer, so i will link against all the source files (i heard there are lib files somewhere, but building example indexer with VS7 i didn't seem to find a way to make them, yet).

On the plus side, to my disbelief I was able to compile simpleindexer example after following your last paragraph in read-me file.

and still - a nice VC6 project file wouldn't hurt.! :)

Answer (score 0):

Janisb - there are already PHP bindings for Xapian, that wrap all the Xapian class definitions. You can download prebuilt binaries for these at the website above.

Sean, thanks for all your work - once I track down the appropriate 64bit resources (oh and some spare time ;-) I'll be adding this to the Windows build files. I agree the documentation is sparse, but the main development is Unix based so we're always playing catch-up to some degree. Patches to the current documentation are very welcome via the Xapian bug tracker (accessible from www.xapian.org).